# Geting h1's border-bottom closer

Tags: html, css

This is my piece of **HTML**:

```
<header>
    <hgroup>
        <h1><span>GUITARRA</span></h1>
        <h2>Profesor</h2>
    </hgroup>
</header>
```

This is my **CSS** (added * rules):

```
*{
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: arial;
}

header h1{
    font-size: 42px;
}

header h1 span{
    border-bottom: 3px solid red; 
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

The problem here is that I want to apply the "underline" effect closer than this:
[image: Guitarra word underlined preview]

And by this closer, I mean...:
[image: Guitarra word underlined closer preview]

If I use `text-decoration: underlined;` I get a closer but very thin line, and that's not the desired effect.

Is there a way to do it?

**EDIT**

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arkl1te/kZxn3/)

Comment: The css that I'm showing is everything that I applied and/or related to it, so there's no `padding`.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle demo?

Comment: @Fabián Browsers use a default stylesheet, which does add padding and margin to h1 elements. See my answer below.

Comment: @All, giving solution is good, but explaining why is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6b68/1/)

```
header h1 span {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    font-size: inherit;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Just adjust the height to move the underline up and down as needed.

Comment: This one is quite cleaver, you can set the height to 0 and still get a border!

Answer (score 3):

If you want absolutely awesome control of the underline position, try this:

```
header h1 {
    font-size: 42px;
}
header h1 span {
    font-size: inherit;
    position: relative;
}
header h1 span:before {
    content: '';
    border-top: 3px solid red;
    font-size: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 6px;
}
```

Add a pseudo element to create the underline, and then use absolute positioning to adjust the vertical placement.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Xsk4R/

Comment: Indeed. I like this better than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your padding is set to 0 then I would imagine the line-height of your h1 is creating the gap. Try reducing the line-height (you'll probably just have to go for what looks right) and you should be able to put the underline wherever you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Set a `line-height` on your `h1` tag

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/CUhXp/

```
line-height: 30px;
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
padding-bottom:0px;
```

on the h1.

there is a auto padding, so this will take it away.